# Object in edit mode moves with giant step, can't make precise adjustments

Tags: edit-mode

I'm trying to edit a mesh in blender, but when I try to move a vertex it moves by a set amount that is ridiculously far from the original position, and there's no ability to place it at any point in between. This happens regardless of whether or not proportional editing is being used.

[image: selected vertex]

[image: vertex after first visible change due to cursor movement]

Comment: Proportional edit is off but snapping is on. Snapping is actually the first thing to check when you see that kind of behaviour

Comment: This solved my problem, thanks!